# count number of transitions from 0 to 1 and indices where 1 first appears

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

I want to measure the number of transitions from 0 to 1.
So, in the above example it should count 1.

Also, I want to find the indices where the first occurrence of 1 appears.
So, it should be [1, 9]

In this example:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
```

it should still be 1 since only one time we transited from 0 to 1.
the indices should be [1, 9]

In the last :

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

it should count 2.
the indices should be [1, 9, 15]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, you can do:

```
sum(diff(x) == 1)

[1] 2
```

For the second part:

```
c(which.max(x == 1), which(diff(x) == 1) + 1)

[1]  1  9 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Number of transitions between 0 and 1 :

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
sum(head(x, -1) == 0 & tail(x, -1) == 1)
#[1] 2
```

Indices where the first occurrence of 1 appears

```
with(rle(x), cumsum(lengths)[values == 1] - lengths[values == 1] + 1)
#[1]  1  9 15
```